# order of events in userform

Tags: events, excel, userform, vba

So,
If i have this function in a userform:

```
function myFunc() as String
    Me.Show vbModal
    stringVar = "Second"
end function
```

and I have the click event of the lone command button on said userform:

```
Private Sub cmdbutton_Click()
    Unload Me
    stringVar = "First"                                                  
End Sub
```

My question is, when I call that function ("MyFunc") from somewhere, will the click event of the button ("cmdButton")  continue processing before the function is allowed to continue, or is it basically a coin toss? this `stringVar` variable is a private variable of the userform. it gets set in the click event of that button, but I want to use it in the function, after the click has happened. (there will be other components on the form, calculations, etc...)

so is there any risk that the function will continue processing before the click event finishes? If the function continues before the click event, then the variable wont be set properly

Comment: Why would the click event process anything if the event doesnt get fired, i.e. if button is not clicked?

Comment: well obviously it wouldnt... but if the button is pressed.. then will the click event finish before processing goes back to `myFunc`?

Comment: when myfunc is called the form is opened modally, so processing in `myfunc` stops untill the form is closed. I just need to know if when the form closes in the click event, will processing continue in the click before going back to `myfunc`

Comment: That is because you have the userform in Modal form. Make it Modeless.

Comment: you're not reading what I'm saying.... `I just need to know if when the form closes in the click event, will processing continue in the click before going back to myfunc` so will it or not? I want it the way I have it, it works, I just want to know if it will ALWAYS work.. or if maybe one time processing will go back to `myfunc` before it finishes the click, in which case it breaks.

Comment: The line `stringVar = "Second"` will not run till the time the userform is unloaded as you are showing the form in modal mode.

Comment: Regarding `stringVar = "First"`, yes that will run after the `unload me` is issued.

Comment: thanks you siddarth! You save the day as usual. make it an answer and ill check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, when I call that function ("MyFunc") from somewhere, will the click event of the button ("cmdButton") continue processing before the function is allowed to continue, or is it basically a coin toss?

Let me explain it with an image followed by a description

[image]

1. When you run the function, the first line is executed. Now since the form is shown as modal, the next line which is `stringVar = "Second"` will not run till the time the userform is unloaded.
2. The next line which will execute in the above scenario is `Unload Me`. However, it doesn't mean that any code after that will not run. `Unload Me` is not like `Exit Do` or `Exit For`. It just unloads the object and in no way stop further execution of the script/code.
3. So obviously the next line which is executed is `stringVar = "First"` and it reaches `End Sub`
4. This is the time the control has been returned to the function and it continues to execute the next line which is `stringVar = "Second"`

Hope this makes sense. If it doesn't then please feel free to ask whatever doubts that you have.

You can also see the execution of the code by stepping through it using <kbd>F8</kbd>.

**For further reading:** [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: I did see that in the debugger, I just wanted confirmation that it will ALWAYS happen this way, and it wasn't some coin toss that usually went that way. Helpfull as always siddharth :)